RXJS observing an observable on a possibly undefined object
Given two sources, one of which might be undefined how can I combineLatest of the two?
const observable1 = interval(100);
const observable2 = this.ref?.observable; // this is a reference to an angular viewchild that will not exist until some unknown point in the future

combineLatest([observable1, observable2]).subscribe(...)

I need the output observable that I'm subscribing to subscribe to this.ref.observable as soon as this.ref is defined (but I don't know when that will be).
What I tried...
observable1.pipe(
   startWith(of(true)),
   switchMap((_) => interval(10)),
   skipWhile((_) => !this.ref),
   switchMap((_) => observable1),
   combineLatestWith(this.ref?.observable ?? EMPTY),
)
.subscribe((val1, val2]) => {...})

But a) I couldn't figure out what the TS errors I was getting around the types returned from the combineLatestWith and b) that seems overly complicated for what seems like a simple issue!
Is there a simpler way of getting emissions from a source observable if the object the source observable is on may be undefined at the time I want to start observing?

can u paste the error you get here?

@Marlon Sorry not an error, but the subscription is never triggered.

What are you really encountering a problem with? Is this about observables or is this about knowing “when the view child is ready”?

Create an BehaviorSubject that initially has null
subject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

Then on ngOnInit or constructor subscribe for the changes!
ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.pipe(
       startWith(of(true)),
       switchMap((_) => interval(10)),
       skipWhile((_) => !this.ref),
       switchMap((_) => observable1),
       combineLatestWith(this.ref?.observable ?? EMPTY),
    )
    .subscribe((val1, val2]) => {...})
}

The view child generally becomes visible on ngAfterViewInit.
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.viewChild?.nativeElement) {
        this.subject.next(this.viewChild.nativeElement);
    }
}


In this case the viewchild is nested within a bunch of conditionals so may not be available in ngAfterViewInit - I could use the same conditions to trigger the subscribe I just thought there might be a more elegant way...

@RobinSouthgate When the conditionals are true, the view child will be visible also, you can also consider, view children, which has a changes observable you can subscribe to!

My Solution for your Problem
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  QueryList,
  ViewChildren,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, combineLatest, interval, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { Site3Child1Component } from './site-3-child-1/site-3-child-1.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-3',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
   <p>site-3 works!</p>
   <ng-container *ngIf="showChild1">
     <app-site-3-child-1 #child1 />
   </ng-container>`,
  styleUrl: './site-3.component.css',
  imports: [Site3Child1Component, CommonModule],
})
export class Site3Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren('child1') children?: QueryList<Site3Child1Component>;

  protected showChild1 = false;

  private observable1 = interval(1000);

  private destroy$ = new Subject();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showChild1 = true;
    }, 2000);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.children?.changes
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((children: QueryList<Site3Child1Component>) => {
        const child1 = children.first;
        if (child1) {
          console.log('child1 is now available');
          combineLatest([this.observable1, child1.observable])
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(([observable1, child1Value]) => {
              console.log(observable1, child1Value);
            });
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }
}

//child
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-3-child-1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './site-3-child-1.component.html',
  styleUrl: './site-3-child-1.component.css',
})
export class Site3Child1Component {
  public observable = interval(3000);
}

